# Sharepoint Infopath form - How to tell if custom code eixsts

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm working with a Sharepoint project that was migrated from 2007 to 2010. There is not history on who originally created the project or how they did this. So, if the original developer used a Visual Studio project to add custom code to the form, that VS project does not exist.

Is there any way to tell if an existing form has custom code written for it? If I want to add my own custom code, the only way I can do this is go into the form properties and select "remove existing code". Then I can create a new project and add code.

Is it the case that if I cannot find the original VS project, that this is my only choice...to remove any existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can't find the original project, then you're out of luck - you have to remove the code and rewrite as necessary.

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2013/recover-make-changes-infopath-forms-sharepoint.htm

(Paragraph at the bottom of the article, just before "3 ways you can find out whether code was written for a form template")